# Static reward amount for AdMob's Rewarded Video Ad

Tags: java, android, admob, rewardedvideoad

My AdMob's Rewarded Video Ad unit is configured to reward the value 20, as can be seen in the following screenshot, taken from my AdMob's console:

[image]

Though, after a successful reward callback, I get the value 10 as the reward amount:

[image]

I currently use test ads, therefore I assume that the value 10 is the default amount for a Rewarded Video test Ad, but couldn't confirm this as a fact.

Is that true, or am I missing something?
I would like to be sure that the correct amount will be used in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the risk and just published my app to the Play Store and I can confirm that the Rewarded Video Ad is now working as expected - the `RewardItem` provided in `onRewarded` is indeed packed with the configured value that was set in AdMob.